# How can I find the hostname of a machine I can FTP into?

Tags: centos, ftp

I'm able to FTP into a site at $job on an IP that I'm expecting to be a different machine. It appears to be a server that a previous sys admin setup without documenting anything about it. Since I'm able to FTP in, is there any way to figure out what server I'm actually ftp'd into since I'm accessing it via IP?

Using DNS is sadly not an option as the name does not resolve for whatever it is.

Based on our standards, I believe this is a CentOS box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftp` will not be able to tell you the hostname. Since it's a CentOS-box, why not ssh in to it? Or, since you are the owner, have a look at the terminal?

Comment: This was a much simpler solution...that's what I get for posting on serverfault before I've had my coffee.

Thanks man.

Comment: If you can `ftp` in, you may be able to `cd` into `/etc` and grab a copy of the `hostname` file.  But +1 for `ssh`.

Comment: I checked in /etc and didn't see a hostname file, appreciate the idea though...would have been very useful if ssh didn't work.